# How can I change the position of checkbox in react-native-select-multiple, I want it after label

Tags: react-native

I want to change the position of checkbox from left to right side of the label. My requirement is like that. Any help in this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a creenshot of the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned below try to use something like this. try `react-native-check-box` instead `react-native-select-multiple`

[link :react-native-check-box](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-box)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box';

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedItems: new Map(),
    fruits: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
  };

  render() {
    console.log('thisstate', !!this.state.checkedItems.get('Apples'));

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        {this.state.fruits.map((item, index) => (
          <CheckBox
            index={index}
            style={{ width: '60%', paddingVertical: 20, alignSelf: 'center' }}
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({
                checkedItems: this.state.checkedItems.set(
                  item,
                  !this.state.checkedItems.get(item)
                ),
              });
            }}
            isChecked={!!this.state.checkedItems.get(item)}
            leftText={item}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailsScreen;
```

feel free for doubts.